# How to divide number into integer pieces that are each a multiple of n?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

Had a hard time coming up with a concise title for this.  I'm sure there are terms for what I want to accomplish and there is no doubt a common algorithm to accomplish what I'm after - I just don't know about them yet.

I need to break up a number into n pieces that are each a multiple of 50.  The number is itself a multiple of 50.  Here is an example:
Divide 5,000 by 3 and end up with three numbers that are each multiples of 50:

- 1,650
- 1,700
- 1,650

I also would like to have the numbers distributed so that they flip back and forth, here is an example with more numbers to illustrate this:
Divide 5,000 by 7 and end up with 7 numbers that are each multiples of 50:

- 700
- 750
- 700
- 750
- 700
- 700
- 700

Note that in the above example I'm not worried that the extra 50 is not centered in the series, that is I don't need to have something like this:

- 700
- 700
- 750  <--- note the '50s' are centered
- 700
- 750  <--- note the '50s' are centered
- 700
- 700

Hopefully I've asked this clearly enough that you understand what I want to accomplish.

**Update: Here is the function I'll be using.**

```
var number = 5000;
var n = 7;
var multiple = 50;

var values = getIntDividedIntoMultiple(number, n, multiple)

function getIntDividedIntoMultiple(dividend, divisor, multiple)
{
    var values = [];
    while (dividend> 0 && divisor > 0)
    {
        var a = Math.round(dividend/ divisor / multiple) * multiple;
        dividend -= a;
        divisor--;
        values.push(a);
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: From your examples, it seems that you want to have each of the smaller numbers as equal as possible.  Is that correct?  A trivial solution, for example, would be to take 50 for each of the first n-1 numbers and the remainder for the rest, but I assume that's not what you are looking for...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var number = 5000;
var n = 7;

var values = [];
while (number > 0 && n > 0) {
    var a = Math.floor(number / n / 50) * 50;
    number -= a;
    n--;
    values.push(a);
}  // 700 700 700 700 700 750 750
```

**Edit**

You can alternate `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` to obtain the desired result:

```
while (number > 0 && n > 0) {
    if (a%2 == 0)
        a = Math.floor(number / n / 50) * 50;
    else
        a = Math.ceil(number / n / 50) * 50;
    number -= a;
    n--;
    values.push(a);
}  // 700 750 700 750 700 700 700
```

Comment: Nice examples, how would you extend it to toggle the round up and round down so that you have 700, 750, 700, 750, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, that works well.  I was just stepping through the code in the debugger and watching how it worked and I get it.

Comment: Nice and clean, provided a JS example which wasn't needed but is appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't saying it as a negative, was just commenting that the extra effort for a JS example was appreciated considering you first supplied a c example.

Answer (score 3):

```
// i - an integer multiple of k
// k - an integer
// n - a valid array length
// returns an array of length n containing integer multiples of k
// such that the elements sum to i and the array is sorted,
// contains the minimum number of unique elements necessary to
// satisfy the first condition, the elements chosen are the
// closest together that satisfy the first condition.
function f(i, k, n) {
  var minNumber = (((i / k) / n) | 0) * k;
  var maxNumber = minNumber + k;
  var numMax = (i - (minNumber * n)) / k;
  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n - numMax; ++i) {
    nums[i] = minNumber;
  }
  for (var i = n - numMax; i < n; ++i) {
    nums[i] = maxNumber;
  }
  return nums;
}
```

So your second example would be

```
f(5000, 50, 7)
```

which yields

```
[700,700,700,700,700,750,750]
```

Comment: Nice to see a different approach, not exactly what I wanted as the 750 values are back loaded consecutively.

Answer (score 2):

Let a be your starting number, k - number of parts you want to divide to.
Suppose, that b = a/n.
Now you want to divide b into k close integer parts.

- Take k numbers, each equal to b/k (integer division).
- Add 1 to first b%k numbers.
- Multiply each number by n.

Example: 
a = 5000, n = 50, k = 7.
b = 100
Starting series {14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14}
Add 1 to first 2 integers {15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14}.
Multiply by 50 {750, 750, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700}.

Comment: At first it "wooosh!" over my head w/ the terminology but after playing with some code I see what you're saying now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the same as dividing a number `X` into `N` integer pieces that are all within 1 of each other *(just multiply everything by 50 after you've found the result)*.  Doing this is easy - set all `N` numbers to `Floor(X/N)`, then add 1 to `X mod N` of them.

Answer (score 2):

I see your problem as basically trying to divide a sum of money into near-equal bundles of bills of a certain denomination.

For example, dividing 10,000 dollars into 7 near-equal bundles of 50-dollar bills.

```
function getBundles(sum, denomination, count, shuffle)
{
  var p = Math.floor(sum / denomination);
  var q = Math.floor(p / count);
  var r = p - q * count;

  console.log(r + " of " + ((q + 1) * denomination)
      + " and " + (count - r) + " of " + (q * denomination));

  var b = new Array(count);
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    b[i] = (r > 0 && (!shuffle || Math.random() < .5 || count - i == r)
        ? (--r, q + 1) : q)
      * denomination;
  }

  return b;
}

// Divide 10,000 dollars into 7 near-equal bundles of 50-dollar bills
var bundles = getBundles(10000, 50, 7, true);

console.log("bundles: " + bundles);
```

Output:

```
4 of 1450 and 3 of 1400
bundles: 1400,1450,1450,1400,1450,1400,1450
```

If the last argument `shuffle` is `true`, it distributes the extra amount randomly between the bundles.

Answer (score 1):

My algorithm provides even distribution of remainder across parts:

```
function splitValue(value, parts, multiplicity)
{
    var result = [];
    var currentSum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parts; i++)
    {
        result[i] = Math.round(value * (i + 1) / parts / multiplicity) * multiplicity - currentSum;
        currentSum += result[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

For value = 5000, parts = 7, multiplicity = 50 it returns

```
[ 700, 750, 700, 700, 700, 750, 700 ]
```

Comment: multiple is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toList(divide(50, 5000, 3)));
    System.out.println(toList(divide(50, 5000, 7)));
    System.out.println(toList(divide(33, 6600, 7)));
}

private static ArrayList<Integer> toList(int[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(args.length);
    for (int i : args)
        list.add(i);
    return list;
}

public static int[] divide(int N, int multiplyOfN, int partsCount) {
    if (N <= 0 || multiplyOfN <= N || multiplyOfN % N != 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid args");

    int factor = multiplyOfN / N;
    if (partsCount > factor)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid args");

    int parts[] = new int[partsCount];
    int remainingAdjustments = factor % partsCount;
    int base = ((multiplyOfN / partsCount) / N) * N;

    for (int i = 0; i < partsCount; i ++) {
        parts[i] = (i % 2 == 1 && remainingAdjustments-- > 0) ? base + N : base;
    }

    return parts;
}
```

Comment: Wrong language. At least it shows how much code you need to type in Java to do a simple thing ;) (no offense)